# PHP получение значения из блока

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Здраствуйте.
Возникла проблема с **PHP** и **MySQL**.
В блоки записываются данные из БД с помощью `$row['что-то']`.
Создал отдельную страницу `details.php` в которую будут вводиться все данные о определенном блоке. Например, есть 2 блока с идентификаторами 1 и 2. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на блок с ид 1 открывалась страница `details.php` и вводила все данные из БД о блоке с ид 1 ? (и также самое с блоком 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант.

Либо сделать ссылку на `details.php` и передавать `id` GET параметром. Например:

```
http://site.ru/details.php?id=1
```

Либо делать редирект через JavaScript в событии `onClick` (`document.location.href` [в помощь](http://ivan.rolik.name/2013/12/26/object-and-properties-document-location/)).

Comment: $Streletz Спасибо, действительно помогло! :)